# Reading CodeIgniter config values from database instead of config file

Tags: database, codeigniter, config

As you might know, when you create a new project with CI you'll have to **manually enter** base url, **encryption key** in config/config.php. I'm trying to overcome this and is hence looking for a way to **read** those values **from a database instead** - making the installation for a customer and the **set up time** as a whole **decrease** a lot.

A customer isn't able to edit a PHP file's variables, but is most likely able to, with some guidance, enter base url and have a encryption key automatically filled in by the system.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Zar, since version 2 you *don't* have to enter a base URL in the config file at all. Also, you can't start a session without an encryption key, so you might as well write the value to file with an installation script that doesn't require a session/login, which then means you may not need to read config from the DB at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course! Add a [hook - post_controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) and set these config values through that file.

`config/hooks.php`

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(  'class'    => 'MyOtherClass',
                                    'function' => 'MyOtherfunction',
                                    'filename' => 'Myotherclass.php',
                                    'filepath' => 'hooks');
```

`hooks/myotherclass.php`

```
<?

class MyOtherClass {

    function MyOtherfunction() {

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $row = $CI->db->get_where('configs', array('site_id' => 1))->row();

        $CI->config->set_item('base_url', $row->base_url);

    }

}
```

Basicly you set these values before they're used in any controller or similiar.

Comment: I guess it'd be a preformance boost to cache these values? Thanks!

Comment: Well ye, but it's basicly just a sole simple query run on each page load. I doubt you will get to the point where this would be worth caching, since the amount of sites may not extend millions? :) It's worth saving gained result to a global value, so you can reuse it for other parts of your site.

Comment: @Zar: You should just write the values directly to file/cache as soon as they are saved by the user. You really don't need the DB for this at all.

Answer (score 3):

As far [Codeigniter 3.1.7](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) `pre_controller` won't work because it will return **NULL** value while initializing  `$CI =& get_instance();`

**To solve this:**

Change the hook point from `pre_controller` to `post_controller_constructor`

**Modified source:**

`config/hooks.php`

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(  'class'    => 'MyOtherClass',
                                'function' => 'MyOtherfunction',
                                'filename' => 'Myotherclass.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks');
```

and in `hooks/myotherclass.php`

```
<?

class MyOtherClass {

    function MyOtherfunction() {

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $row = $CI->db->get_where('configs', array('site_id' => 1))->row();

        $CI->config->set_item('base_url', $row->base_url);

    }

}
```

Now it will work!

Comment: **post controller** is useless if you want to use these config settings in controller. because from your method it won't set config until it finish executing controller code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class name extends CI_Controller {
    public $DB1;
    public $MSSQL;
    public function __construct()
     {
    parent::__construct();
        $userid = $this->session->userdata('userids');
          $this->load->model('kubix');
          $result = $this->kubix->databaseconncetion($userid);
        foreach ($result as $deta)
          {

      $this->MSSQL=$db['MSSQL'] = array(
      'hostname' => $deta["Db_base_ip"],
      'username' => $deta["Db_username"],
      'password' => $deta["db_password"],
      'database' => $deta["Db_base_name"],
      'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
      'dbprefix' => '',
      'pconnect' => FALSE,
      'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
      'cache_on' => FALSE,
      'cachedir' => '',
      'char_set' => 'utf8',
      'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
      'swap_pre' => '',
      'encrypt' => FALSE,
      'compress' => FALSE,
      'stricton' => FALSE,
      'failover' => array(),
      'save_queries' => TRUE);
      $this->DB1 = $this->load->database($this->MSSQL, TRUE);
    $sql = "SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM AccountsFinancialYearMaster where Active=1 ";
        $query = $this->DB1->query( $sql);
        $result= $query->result_array();
RETURN $result;
```