# how to make a pattern modifier for replacing a value iin php file?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a file with the following prototype

```
<?php
$config['some_key']='some_value';
$config['some_other_key']='some_other_value';

//End of file config.php
```

I have a file that fetches and shows value of these variables to the administrator, then he changes some of these settings if he wishes so. so I have to update the config.php file in order to save changes. For example `some_value` has to change to `new_value` like this:

```
<?php
$config['some_key']='new_value';
$config['some_other_key']='some_other_value';

//End of file config.php
```

I've researched a little and found out that one of my options is to use `file_get_contents()` to read the file the use `preg_replace()` to apply my changes the write the file again, but I have no idea how to make a pattern and a replacement for my purpose.
I would really appreciate any help from you guys, thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouln't you be served better with either reading and writing an ini/xml/json file or using a database?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter and there are config files and a config class which reads these files, usual way to update config files in codeigniter is to open the file and change it manually, what I'm trying to do is making an interface for it

Comment: You could use a database for storing these values then and have a hook that load the settings from there and `get_instance()->config->set_item()` them. Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674341/reading-codeigniter-config-values-from-database-instead-of-config-file) perhaps.

Comment: looks good, I would consider that due the lack of security in my own way of solving the problem, thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind that the format of your file changes, you can make this more robust with [`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). This function will export out your `$config` variable in a format like this:

```
array (
     'some_key' => 'some_value',
     'some_other_key' => 'some_other_value',
)
```

In the part of the code where the administration page have the posted changes you can do something like this:

```
// load in the config file
include 'config.php'; 
// now you will have a local $config variable from the file

// update the config array with the data posted by the user
foreach ($_POST['changes'] as $key => $value) {
    $config[$key] = $value;
}
// write the $config variable back to the file
file_put_contents('config.php', '$config = '.var_export($config, true));
```

Of course having the users directly write executable code in your application have horrible security implications with a malicious user.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I used hooks as you suggested and it works like a charm, thanks again